# sql cohort analysis

Tags: sql

As an input, you have 2 tables :
- one with user_id, signup_timestamp
- and a second one with user_id, order_timestamp

My understanding:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually it is hard to solve this because you cannot display the answer effectively with a simple table. But I'm pretty sure this will match your willings. The code may have some errors because I'm on the phone.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DATEPART(week, t1.signup_timestamp) AS week, count(signup) AS purchases
FROM table1) 
t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT 
DATEPART(week, t1.order_timestamp) AS week, count(signup) AS orders 
FROM table2)
t2 
on t1.week = t2.week
```